# Point cloud color blending after registration

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, blending, color-blending

I have succesfully registered two point clouds of the same scene obtained from different camera positions. Color values are different due to changes in light condition between both positions. I would like to know how to perform a smart color blending between two aligned point clouds in order to obtain an uniform color along the global model. Any idea?

I enclose a capture where you can see how color is darker in the cloud on the right.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by smart-coloring ? why not re-color one of your clouds before the registration part.

Comment: What I mean is a smart blending, like alpha or pyramidal blending in a standard 2D-stitching task. I could re-color one of the clouds but if I have N local clouds, at the end I'll need some automatic process. I was thinking about applying some exposure compensation since these rgb changes are due to changes in scene lighting. I guess this could be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to adapt image blending approaches to 3D point clouds, but it's not straightforward at all, so I applied an easier solution that solved my problem for the moment.

Since texture changes are mainly given by changes in scene lighting due to different camera positions, theoretically just a exposure compensation between both clouds should provide good results. I've fixed my problem extending a standard approach of 2D exposure compensation to a 3D scenario. Concretely, just a [gain compensation](http://matthewalunbrown.com/papers/ijcv2007.pdf) (point 6 of the paper) is enough if the lighting difference is low enough.